# H2 - update each row with its index number (0,1,2,3,..)

Tags: java, sql, h2

I have a table in me H2 db, which stores some ordered list:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items 
(
  f_id      INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  f_name    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  f_index   INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
)


|f_id|f_name|f_index|
|1   |A     |1      |
|2   |C     |3      |
|3   |B     |4      |
|4   |D     |2      |
```

When I remove item 'D', I need to update C's index to 2 and B's index to 3.

And I am going crazy when triyng to do this. I don't want to simply

```
UPDATE items SET f_index = f_index-1 WHERE f_index > ?
```

because I am afraid my table can contain gaps (caused by unknown reasons), so I look for a something like

```
SqlRowSet rowSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("SELECT f_name FROM items ORDER BY f_index");
int i = 0;
while (rowSet.next()) {
    String name = rowSet.getString("f_name");
    jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE items SET f_index = ? WHERE f_name= ?", i++, name);   
}
```

but more elegant.

Is there any way to achieve my needs with H2?

Comment: What is f_index exactly? Is it just the PK of the table? If so, you shouldn't worry about updating it.

Comment: why do you need to update the f_index?

Comment: @nasukkin I've provided CREATE TABLE sql

Comment: @Guenther I need to allow my users to reorder items as they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use h2 then you can use the following statement

```
merge into items (f_id, f_index) key(f_id) select f_id, rownum()  from items order by f_index
```

Comment: This is perfect! One quick note that `rownum()` starts with `1`, and I had indexes from 0, which caused `Unique index or primary key violation`, so i used `merge into items (f_id, f_index) key(f_id) select f_id, rownum()-1  from items order by f_index`